# Restoring the image of a face's plane

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am using an API to analyze faces in Matlab, where I get for each picture a 3X3 rotation matrix of the face's orientation, telling which direction the head is pointing. 
I am trying to normalize the image according to that matrix, so that it will be distorted to get the image of the face's plane. This is something like 'undoing' the projection of the face to the camera plane. For example, if the head is directed a little to the left, it will stretch the left side to (more or less) preserve the face's original proportions.

Tried using 'affine2d' and 'projective2d' with 'imwarp', but it didn't achieve that goal

Answer (score 1):

Achieving your goal with simple tools like affine transformations seems impossible to me since a face is hardly a flat surface. An extreme example: Imagine the camera recording a profile view of someone's head. How are you going to reconstruct the missing half of the face?

There have been successful attempts to change the orientation of faces in images and real-time video, but the methods used are quite complex:

> [We] propose a gaze correction method that needs just a
>   single webcam. We apply recent shape deformation techniques
>   to generate a 3D face model that matches the user’s face. We
>   then render a gaze-corrected version of this face model and
>   seamlessly insert it into the original image.

(Giger et al., https://graphics.ethz.ch/Downloads/Publications/Papers/2014/Gig14a/Gig14a.pdf)

Comment: Thanks. What I am looking for can be much less accurate, and can represent the head as a ball or a flat surface. What solution could be used for that?